# get all data and insert to arraylist from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, arraylist

i wanto get all color data from firebase then insert to arraylist, and the color data structure like image below
[image]

and here is when i want to insert to Arraylist

```
private void getDataDetailProduct() {
    imageReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                for (DataSnapshot childSbapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    String id = childSbapshot.getKey();

                    ArrayList<String>images = new ArrayList<>();                        
                    images.add(String.valueOf(childSbapshot.getChildren()));
                }
                initSlideImage();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What error you are facing?

Comment: there is no data inside images

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<String>images = new ArrayList<>(); 

private void getDataDetailProduct() {
    imageReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                for (DataSnapshot childSbapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    String id = childSbapshot.getKey();
                    images.add(String.valueOf(childSbapshot.child("colors1").getValue()));
                    images.add(String.valueOf(childSbapshot.child("colors2").getValue()));
                    images.add(String.valueOf(childSbapshot.child("colors3").getValue()));
                }
        initSlideImage();
        }}

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for the the solution, but total color data is flexibel, sometime there is 3 colors, sometimes 5 colors. this is why i use ArrayList for save flexible data array..

Comment: Then you can also use FirebaseListAdapter or FirebaseRecyclerAdapter .